# How to install and configure Openvpn/Azure vpn client in CI pipeline in Azure DevOps either with certificate based auth or AAD auth

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, openvpn, azure-vpn

I'm new to Azure DevOps. My requirement is to automate Terraform code using ci/cd pipelines. The problem is that all the Azure resources are internal and they can be accessed only using point to site VPN.
Currently we are installing the Azure VPN client in local machine and connecting to the resources through AAD authentication. But I want to do the same in CI pipeline in Azure DevOps

So I need a way to install and configure Openvpn/Azure vpn client  in CI pipeline in Azure DevOps either with certificate based auth or AAD auth so that I can access the resources.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.